# How to get the text which dragged from other place in pyQT?

Tags: python, pyqt

I'd like to drag some texts to pyQT's TextEdit form MS Word or webpage or other places where there are some words.

My key codes are here:

```
    self.inputBox = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(xxxx)
    self.inputBox.dragEnterEvent = self.onDragEnter

    def onDragEnter(self, event):
        content = self.inputBox.toPlainText()
        print(content)
        print(123)
```

While I drag some words to the textEdit, the console will print 123, so it means that the `onDragEnter` method is been called. However, the text I dragged could never been printed in the console.

So, what's wrong in my codes? And how to change the code so that it could do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you would subclass the widget you want to add drag-n-drop support to and reimplement the `dragEnterEvent`, `dragMoveEvent`, `dragLeaveEvent`, and `dropEvent` methods.  Many widgets already have support for drag-n-drop, including the `QTextEdit`.  As long as `acceptDrops()` is True (which it is by default), drag-n-drop like you're talking about should already work.  But if you want to do it manually

```
def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
    if event.mimeData().hasText():
        event.accept()
    else:
        event.ignore()

def dropEvent(self, event):
    if event.mimeData().hasText():
        text = event.mimeData().text()
        self.insertPlainText(text)
```

Comment: Thanks, and I will have a try later. If it works, I will come back and upvote for you.

Comment: hi, it can not work. I have define a class called myEdit(QtWidgets.QTextEdit), and place your code in the class, but how can I use it?

Comment: While I drag some text to the widget, it will close by itself without any error or exception.